# Trying to hide the title bar on my Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, titlebar

I'm trying to hide the title bar on my app by putting the following code in the manifest file

```
android:label="Sound Board" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

It looks to be working on my tablet, but not on my smart phone.  My tablet is version 3.1 and the smart phone is 2.2

-Ted

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">. It has worked for me across all smart phones from 2.2 to 4.2

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if that theme was available in api level 8 (2.2), but having following code in your `Activity` will provide the same result:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    ...
}
```

Comment: You should actually probably do both.  I find that if you dont declare it in XML, you will see it flash up in the start of the activity